# MSBuild: Update custom modified project property with property sheet setting

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup

I am trying to update Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheet, in which planning to update below mentioned settings.
1. c++ -> General -> optimization -> optimization = Disabled (/Od). 
2. Linker -> General -> output directory = C:\BuildPath.

To complete above mentioned task I have updated existing Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property files in VS 2013. But I am getting a problem, when some projects are having manual output directory project setting (i.e. D:\BuildProjectPath) and those project outdir is not getting updated from Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property files. to update these setting i have to manually select .
let me know how can we resolve this issue.

Comment: What file exactly are you modifying?

Comment: Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user file i am updating with setting.

Comment: VS 2013 does not use this file. What exactly is the original problem you are trying to address?

Comment: We are unable to update vcxproj settings by props file setting. suppose one of setting is changed and saved on vcxproj we are unable to overwrite  those property by props file.

Comment: individual project files can always override common settings and common targets. This is designed behavior of MSBuild.